# How to express return in Haskell in terms of fmap?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

So I found out that `fmap`, a `Functor` function can be expressed in terms of Monadic operator `>>=` and `return` function like this:

```
fmap' :: (Monad m) => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
fmap' g x = x >>= (\y ->
                return (g y))
```

So my first question is how can we implement return function based on `fmap`?

Also if we can implement return function based on `fmap`, can we reduce Haskell expressions in do blocks? Would that produce more elegant code?

For instance:

```
Just x -> do 
    y <- f x
    return (a:y)
```

Comment: ...No, this isn't doable.  Being a monad is a strictly stronger claim than being a functor.  A monad can always be treated as a functor, but the converse is false.

Comment: A Functor doesn't have a way to create a wrapped value - `fmap` can only transform a wrapped value to another wrapped value. To create a wrapped value you need something more powerful like an Applicative where you have `pure :: a -> f a`.

Comment: And to answer your other question: yes, you can make that code more compact. `do { y <- f x; return (a:y) }` is the same as `fmap (a:) (f x)` (can you prove it? hint: use your equation for `fmap'`).

Comment: Sort of tangential, but there's a well-known function `join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`.  `join` can be written in terms of `>>=` and `id`, and `>>=` can be written in terms of `join` and `fmap`.  You might be interested to work out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We cannot generally implement `return` in terms of `fmap`.  `Monad` is just more powerful than `Functor`.

As an exercise, however, we can try and ask this question: what second operation, if any, would make it possible to implement `return` in turns of `fmap`?  We can attack this question by looking at the types.  (We'll use `pure` from the `Applicative` class instead of `return`—they're basically the same operation.)

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
pure :: Applicative f => a -> f a
```

Well, one possible way this could go is if we have the following function:

```
-- This is like the standard `const` function, but restricted to the `()` type:
const' :: a -> () -> a
const' a = \() -> a
```

Then we can write this, which is "almost" `pure`/`return`:

```
almostThere :: Functor f => a -> f () -> f a
almostThere a = fmap (const' a)
```

And then if we had the following class, we could write `pure` in terms of it:

```
class Functor f => Pointed f where
    unit :: f ()

pure :: Pointed f => a -> f a
pure a = almostThere a unit
```

To make a long story short, what this boils down to is that `return`, `pure` and `unit` all are functions that allow you to make an `f` from scratch, while `fmap` only allows you to make an `f` if you already have *another one*.  There is no way you can use `fmap` to implement `return`/`pure` unless you have access to some third operation that has the "power" to make an `f` from scratch.  The `unit` operation I showed is probably the simplest one that has this "power."

Answer (score 2):

The simplest example of a functor where `return` is just impossible is `(,) a`:

```
instance Functor ((,) a) where
  fmap f (a, x) = (a, f x)
```

But to make this a monad, to implement `return`, you'd need to generate an `a` value (for any type!) out of thin air. The only way to do it would be `return x = (undefined, x)`, which is hardly a solution...

Comment: This is for general a, however. There is a perfectly good Monad instance when a itself is a Monoid - the Writer Monad used to be implemented as a newtype around this, before it was made a synonym for WriterT Identity.